# How do you add functionality to iOS Control Center

Tags: ios, ios7, controls, center, spotify

Using Spotify Radio today and noticed that they have substituted a menu button for "<<" on the Control Center.  When you press it you get the menu on the right.  I've worked with Control Center before through the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter class, but there is no mention of this capability in the docs.  Anyone know how they did it?

This is running on iOS7 so (in theory) it is not an Extension.

[image: iOS Control Center with Spotify]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MPRemoteCommandCenter` is what you need. You can set the `dislikeCommand`, `likeCommand` and `bookmarkCommand` properties to perform the actions you need, and override the `localizedTitle` properties of those commands to change the text. Unfortunately, as can be seen in the screenshot, you can't customise the icons of the commands.